# Where can I find a list of common enzyme cofactors and/or co-enzymes?

Tags: metabolism, literature

Where can I find a list of enzyme cofactors and/or co-enzymes, ordered by how common they are?

For example, $O_2$, $H_2O$, $ATP$, $ADP$, $NAD$, should be ranked in the first places, because they participate in most reactions.

Comment: $H_2O$ is not a cofactor for any enzyme.

Comment: Also oxygen cannot be called a cofactor. It is just an electron acceptor- in a way a co-enzyme.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I have edited to include co-enzymes.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/CoFactor/) out. This resource lists organic cofactors and the associated enzymes. 
See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cofactor_%28biochemistry%29) page also.

Many metals also serve as prosthetic groups in enzymes. They include- Magnesium, Manganese, Iron, Cobalt, Nickel, Copper, Zinc, Molybdenum.

FeS clusters are also an important part in many important enzymes in mitochondria and plastids.

Answer (score 3):

### Cofactor:

coenzymes are organic molecules that are required by certain enzymes to carry out catalysis.

### Database:

[CoFactor - The organic enzyme cofactor database](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/CoFactor/) of EBI

### Examples:

[image]