# What are the chemical characteristics of cofactors that functionally differentiate them from the side chains of amino acids?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology, metabolism, enzymes

Cofactors are essential for the function of many enzymes, such as NAD+ in the glycolytic pathway - I was wondering how the chemical properties of these cofactors allow them to fulfil their function and/or what it is about the chemical properties of amino acid side chains that limits their utility in the kind of reactions that require cofactors.

Comment: Are you interested in all cofactors, or only organic ones? (see also: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19896/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-common-enzyme-cofactors-and-or-co-enzymes)